# Scrum - Burndown - What happend when the remaing hours is 0 but the story is not finished

Tags: jira, scrum, jira-agile, burndowncharts

I'm new on Scrum, and I have a question about Burndown chart.

Where I work, we use the burndown chart with remaining hours (not points), so I have a question about what to do when a task consume all the estimate hours but it is not finished.

For ex: an story was estimated with 10 hours, but the team already used 10 or 12 o 20hrs so Jira shows as remaining hours 0 (it shows cero once the spent time is equal or higher than the estimated)
The issue is that when I build the Burndown, the story said that the remaining is cero, so it looks like the story was finished, but that could not be the real status. How can I reflect that in the Burndown?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's not within the scope for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) You may be able to ask on [another Stack Exchange site](//stackexchange.com/sites#name), for example [pm.se] or [softwareengineering.se]. Be sure to read the on-topic page in the help center for any site on which you intend to post a question.

Comment: Since it's about using Jira, it's on topic as being about using tools primarily geared for software development.

Comment: Simply don't use Scrum! If necessary, change the company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Jira**, when you are logging your time spent for the day just add how many hours you think it would take to complete the work to the remaining work field. The original estimate will remain the same, the remaining estimate will update to what you set it to. The original estimate bar will show the change in scope showing the additional scope as an extended grey bar to the right of the green bar.

**From a project managers or a team leads point of view** you should bring this up with them at the next stand-up meeting or immediately ask that question of them so they can plan appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is a common mistake, but in essence, for a **remaining hours** burndown, the consumed hours does not matter, only the **remaining hours** matters.

Each day, the burdown is updated with the estimation of remaining hours to complete the item, without consider how much was already consumed.

e.g.:

If in your case, at the first day **after 6 hours of work**, you estimate you would **still need more 12 hours** of work before complete the task, the **remaining hours for the item is 12**.

Comment: Yes, but if i worked the 12 hours AND the story is not done, the remainig hours will be 0. But the story wasnt complete... Should I re estimate the story to get the new remainig hours? Is that the best practise?

Comment: The remaining hours is the number of hours you estimate are necessary **to complete the item** (usually collected at each daily meeting), so it's impossible to have something with 0 remaining hours that is at the same time not complete.